# Locked Files not showing in PlasticSCM GUI Client

Tags: plasticscm

Dear plastic community,

A colleague and I are currently testing the plasticscm cloud offering in combination with Unity. My setup is as follows:

Setup Lock Rules in the cloud - for example for *.png files. Using Unity 2021.1/2020.3. My colleague checked out a png-file and fbx-file. Both file types are on the organization + project lock rules.

However I cannot see that the files are checked out exclusively in my workspace view and their icons are not changing at all. We are both @main@U_TestPorject@SameServer. I have to try and checkout the files and only then, the system tells me that I cannot edit the files.
Furthermore, Unity is properly showing a blue/orange lock, so this is only in the Plastic GUI.

[CheckedOutFilesOnHisSide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkiqN.png)

[FilesDoNotChangeTheirIconOnMySide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2cfa.png)

[LockedFileIconInUnity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX46o.png)

I would like to know why this is happening? Shouldn't the GUI show me icons for checked-out files from other users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the Plastic SCM GUI doesn't include an icon for the locked items. Only Gluon does.

As a workaround, you can use the "cm listlocks --help" command to show the locked items.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer, Carlos! If I can propose a feature request, this is it. ;) Why wouldn't a user want to have the locks and not up-to-date files presented. The actual update rate could be quite low or even just be included in a click on "Refresh Workspace".  :)